# AllInternalUsers group not working on scratch org

Tags: sharing, scratch-org, user-management, sharing-rule

I was trying to test sharing rules on a custom object: Record_For_Sharing__c

The object's organisation-wide default sharing setting is private for both external and internal users.

I added a sharing rule based on the owner:

```
From: Roles -> SomeRole
To: Public Group -> All Internal Users
```

And then created records from a user with the role "SomeRole"

The problem is that when creating a record, either manually or from sfdx, no internal users have access to the record. This was tried with users with licences **"Salesforce"** and **"Salesforce Platform"**

Also, the correct entries are created in the Record_For_Sharing__Share table.

When doing the same on a developer org, internal users do have access to the records.

Is this a known bug or is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The default scratch org user doesn't have a Role. Did you assign the Role to your user before testing?

Comment: Yes, each user has a custom role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you got the answer you needed but this was confirmed to be a bug by SF.

Here's the link.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003dTYQAY

Another sample scenario is if you create a list view and share with internal users. It won't work either.

No ETA as per latest update. Workaround given is create a new public group with internal users on it or role.